# storing ID in hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function

I have a script here right now that will display(alert) me the ID from the reaction and the First Name and Last Name. Now I need it that when I press this button it will store the ID in a hidden form input so it will send it to the database.

Script that alerts the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printIt(id){
alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
alert(document.getElementById('naam'+id).value); 
}
</script>


<form name="formName">
<input type=hidden id="'.$reactie['id'].'" name="abcName" value="'.$reactie['id'] .'"/>
<input type=hidden id="naam'.$reactie['id'].'" name="abcName" value="Reactie op bericht van '.$reactie['voornaam'].' ' .$reactie['achternaam'] .'"/>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type=button value="Reageer" onclick="printIt(\''.$reactie['id'] .'\')" />
</form>
```

Script that sends the form (where the ID needs to be added) to the database:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){ unset($q1); $q1['reactie'] = $app->check_string($_POST['reactie']); 
$q1['topic_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicid']);
 $q1['klant_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['klantid']);
 $q1['ledenpagina_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['ledenpaginaid']);
 $app->insert_query('reacties', $q1, 'id');
 } 
?> 
<form action="" method="post"> <div class="form-group"> 
<label for="comment">Reactie:</label> 
<textarea class="form-control" name="reactie" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea> 
<input type="hidden" name="klantid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["klant_id"] ?>"> <input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="<?php echo $actieftopicid ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="ledenpaginaid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["ledenpagina_id"]; ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="onderreactieID" value="<?php echo $reactie; ?>"> 
<button type="submit" name="react_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Plaats reactie</button> 

</div> 
</form>
```

**Summary:**

I need the data from the first script ($reactie['id']) when you press the button to fill that in some hidden field. That field needs to go to the database.

So it needs to set that javascript in a hidden field somehow. And when you didnt press anybuttons it needs to be a default 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have a hidden input ready if you otherwise want to set reactieID to 0. You can set the value with javaScript on click event.

```js
console.log("Value of hidden input reactieID = " + document.getElementById('reactieHier').value);
```

```html
<form name="formName">
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type=button value="Reageer" onclick="document.getElementById(
  'reactieHier').value = '5'; console.log('Value of hidden input reactieID = ' + document.getElementById('reactieHier').value)" />
</form>


<form>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="comment">Reactie:</label> 
    <textarea class="form-control" name="reactie" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="hidden" name="klantid" value="99">
    <input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="99"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ledenpaginaid" value="99"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="onderreactieID" value="99">
    <input type="hidden" name="reactieID" id="reactieHier" value="0">
    <button type="submit" name="react_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Plaats reactie</button> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `<input type="hidden" value="0"/>` and when no button pressed you get 0 from hidden input(click on `Check Value` button to see it)

And 'when a button is pressed'(`SetID !` button) will set the given id.

it follows:

```js
function setID(iD){
  var hidden_input = document.getElementById('my_hidden_input');
  hidden_input.value = iD;
  alert('The ID given from button is "' + iD + '".');
  alert('The new value of my_hidden_input is "' + hidden_input.value + '".');
}
function check(){
  alert('The value of my_hidden_input is "' + document.getElementById('my_hidden_input').value + '".');
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input" value="0"/>
<input type="button" value="SetID !" onclick="setID('MyID')" />
<input type="button" value="Check Value" onclick="check()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you make it so it works with my code? I tried doing it for the past 15 minutes but I can't get it to work

Comment: Sure, `onderreactieID` is the name of hidden input you want to be the ID holder? Update your main post with what did you tried yet, this way others can help too